# Ruby on Rails Active Record query joining two tables and query based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables: Transactions and Properties.

I have one condition to satisfy that doesn't require joining tables.

On my Transactions query:

- rows where `sales_date` is in a certain month
- rows where `sold_or_leased` is "leased"

My next condition requires joining properties to transactions so that I can:

- rows where `transactions.sales_date` is in a certain month
- rows where `transactions.sold_or_leased` is null AND
- rows where `properties.for_sale` is false AND `properties.for_lease` is true

Basically, a new column was added to transactions called `sold_or_leased` and a lot of them are null. I need to an extra query to cover the `null` columns.

```
    #test variables for month
    date = "2019-11-01"
    month = Date.parse date

    # below satisfies my first part
    @testobj = Transaction.where(sold_or_leased: "leased")
      .where("sales_date >= ? AND sales_date < ?", month.beginning_of_month, month.end_of_month).count
```

But now I need to extend this query to include properties and test a property column

I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
    @testobj = Transaction.joins(:property)
      .where(sold_or_leased: "leased")
      .where("sales_date >= ? AND sales_date < ?", month.beginning_of_month, month.end_of_month)
      .or(
        Transaction.where(sold_or_lease: nil)
      ).count
```

Also, when I add a join and then an `or` clause, i get an error `Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`

I will share relevant model info:

Transaction Model:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :property
end
```

Property Model:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :property_transaction, class_name: 'Transaction', dependent: :destroy
end
```

With the help of Sebastian, I have the following (which still produces the structural error message):

```
Transaction.joins(:property)
    .where(sales_date: month.all_month,
           sold_or_leased: nil,
           properties: { for_sale: false, for_lease: true })
    .or(
      Transaction.joins(:property)
      .where(sold_or_leased: "leased")
      .where("sales_date >= ? AND sales_date < ?", month.beginning_of_month, month.end_of_month)
    )
```

Comment: How do your models look like?

Comment: I've added an example of what the model looks likes. I cut out irrelevant lines

Comment: I tested your query `Transaction.joins(:property).where(sales_date: month.all_month, sold_or_leased: nil, properties: { for_sale: false, for_lease: true }).or(Transaction.joins(:property).where(sold_or_leased: "leased").where("sales_date >= ? AND sales_date < ?", month.beginning_of_month, month.end_of_month))` and no problem whatsoever 1/2.

Comment: It produces `SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "transactions"."property_id" WHERE ("transactions"."sales_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND "transactions"."sold_or_leased" IS NULL AND "properties"."for_sale" = $3 AND "properties"."for_lease" = $4 OR "transactions"."sold_or_leased" = $5 AND (sales_date >= '2019-11-01' AND sales_date < '2019-11-30'))  [["sales_date", "2019-11-01"], ["sales_date", "2019-11-30"], ["for_sale", false], ["for_lease", true], ["sold_or_leased", "leased"]]` 2/2.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Unfortunately, that produces the `Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]` error and a 500 error in the console, so i'm unable to view the raw query. Not sure why this is working for you and not me

Comment: Can you try adding a `to_sql` at the end of the query you're trying, then add that output to your answer?

Comment: Or can you directly try this `Transaction.joins(:property).where(sales_date: month.all_month).where("(sold_or_leased IS NULL AND properties.for_sale = false AND properties.for_lease = true) OR (sold_or_leased = 'leased')")`?

Comment: Your second query works! I have to verify the data being returned, but it all looks correct. regarding `to_sql`, it was never reaching that part since the `500` error occured on the `.or`. But thank you for all your help. much appreciated!

Comment: Nice! Take your time, check everything is working as expected ;)

Comment: @SebastianPalma confirming the correct data is being returned :). you're a lifesaver! thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to access the `properties` table columns after a join.

Looking to your current code and what you need to get you could try with:

```
Transaction
  .joins(:property)
  .where(sales_date: month.all_month)
  .where(
    "(sold_or_leased IS NULL AND properties.for_sale = false AND properties.for_lease = true) OR
     (sold_or_leased = 'leased')"
  )
```

If you're unable to use the `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#or`, you can always use the SQL `OR` operator within a string argument to `where`.

Notice `month.all_month` produces the whole range of dates for a corresponding month, which when used with `where` is converted to the first and last day of the month:

```
SELECT ... WHERE "transactions"."sales_date" BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND ... [["sales_date", "2019-11-01"], ["sales_date", "2019-11-30"]]
```

Shorter than the `month.beginning_of_month` and `month.end_of_month` variation.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! Your first query helped me get those rows, however, I'm still having trouble combing both queries. After your edit about "structurally compatible", I'm still getting the error ever though I believe I have the right format. I will edit my question with what I have